# snapshot management tool implementation

Tags: filesystems, snapshot, copy-on-write

I want to implement a command-line tool that allows me to take snapshots of the filesystem for linux/unix systems.

I know there are various ways to implement snapshot
Copy-On-Write
Redirect-On-Write
Log File architecture
Split mirror

I think these are by which various file systems allow snapshots. I don’t know how to implement a tool that interacts with the file systems of a device to create and manage snapshots.

I found this tool http://snapper.io/documentation.html but couldn't understand how this works. It would also be helpful if someone could share references to relevant literature.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic "snapshot API". Tools like snapper have backend for all available filesystems and volume management technologies that support snapshoting, detect what technology is used and call appropriate tool(s) to make the snapshot.

For example on btrfs, the situation is quite easy -- you just need to detect what subvolume you want to snapshot based on mountpoint and then run `btrfs subvolume snapshot <source> <destination>` and you have a snapshot. If you have XFS on top of LVM, you need to first freeze the filesystem with `xfs_freeze` and then create the snapshot with `lvcreate --snapshot <vg>/<lv>`. And of course there is also ZFS. And you can take snapshoting abstractly and use something like [OSTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSTree) to create "snapshot" of system files during upgrade for example.

I don't think there is a single book or other source for "snapshots on Linux/Unix". If you are really interested how this works on low level, you can start with generic sources on [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), [LVM](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/index.html) and [ZFS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Project%20and%20Community/Admin%20Documentation.html). But I don't really see point in creating another tool if snapper already exists and does what you want.